# DJANGO: how to use "core" URL in template

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to use a "core" url in my template but I don't know what is happening, It won't let me.

My url is declared here:

url.py: (the djangorestframework is the important one)

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('consumos/', include('consumptions.urls', namespace='consumptions')),
    path('registros/', include('logs.urls', namespace='logs')),
    path('reglas/', include('rules.urls', namespace='rules')),
    path('djangorestframework/', include(router.urls), name="drf"),
    path("", include("authentication.urls")),
    path("", include("dashboard.urls")),
]
```

But when I'm trying to use it in my sidebar I have to

sidebar.html:

```
  <li class="mt-3 nav-item">
    <!-- FIXME: Esta url tiene que haber otra manera de llamarla -->
    <a target="_blank" class="nav-link" href="/djangorestframework">
      <i class="fas fa-cloud"></i>
      <p> API </p>
    </a>
  </li>
```

because it won't let me use it like this:

```
  <li class="mt-3 nav-item">
    <!-- FIXME: Esta url tiene que haber otra manera de llamarla -->
    <a target="_blank" class="nav-link" href="{% url 'drf' %}">
      <i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i>
      <p> API </p>
    </a>
  </li>
```

It says:

> Reverse for 'drf' not found. 'drf' is not a valid view function or
> pattern name.

Why I can not use the name of my url? why do I have to use a relative path?

Thank you!

Comment: try to add namespace instead of name like, include(router.urls, namespace='drf')

Comment: Not working ;( "Specifying a namespace in include() without providing an app_name "

Comment: just to drew your attention : DRF is meant to produce api (`json` format usually) to be publicly available and consumed by other 3rd apps via 3rd library like `axios`. have a look at this tuto https://medium.com/swlh/build-your-first-rest-api-with-django-rest-framework-e394e39a482c